# Table adapts after JSON object

Tags: html, json, angular

I want to create a table that show a JSON-object.
The json-object can have multiple levels so I want to show all data on one row in the table. I.e in the plnkr I want the [object object] to show the Id.

```
  ResultData=[
  {
        "First_name": "xx",
        "Email": "xxxx",
        "Phone": "xxx",
        "countryCode": "+91",
        "order_datetime": "xxx",
        "status": 11,
        "DeviceType": 3,
        "orderId": {
          "orderId": "59081a04c9ff6852a49dd32a",
        },.......
]
```

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YIEe99h9DSLJLhYR3Ma3

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor=" let res of ResultData">
  <td *ngFor=" let key of keys">
    <ng-container *ngIf="key === 'orderId'">
      {{res.orderId.Id}}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="key !== 'orderId'">
    {{res[key]}}
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jy1Ulzxativ9EGlaxKRz?p=preview)

Comment: But if I extend with more data in the object I need to update HTML, would be nice not to need that.

Comment: You can call `Object.keys()` on each property to check if it's a primitive value or an object, and then use a nested `*ngFor` to display these properties. Calling `Object.keys()` in view binding is strongly discouraged, therefore you should make your `keys` already a tree (list with nested item and lists for items that have multiple properties.